# Matrix definition of the Ising XX gate

Tags: matrix-representation

On the English Wikipedia, $XX$ Ising gates are defined in matrix form as :

$$ XX(\phi) = \begin{bmatrix}\cos(\phi)&0&0& -i \sin(\phi)\\
0&\cos(\phi)&-i \sin(\phi) & 0 \\
0 & -i \sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi) & 0 \\
-i \sin(\phi) & 0 & 0 & \cos(\phi) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

However, on the French Wikipedia, the $XX$ Ising gates are defined as :

$$ XX(\phi) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0& -i e^{i \phi}\\
0&1&-i  & 0 \\
0 & -i  & 1 & 0 \\
-i e^{i \phi} & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

From some [sources](http://iontrap.umd.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/nature18648.pdf), I believe the right one is the first one. I would like some confirmations about the second definition being an error, and I would be glad to take any explanation on it. In particular, does this matrix in the second definition corresponds to the definition of another gate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your first option is the correct one, being related to $e^{-i\phi X\otimes X}$, which is
$$ XX(\phi) = \begin{bmatrix}\cos(\phi)&0&0& -i \sin(\phi)\\
0&\cos(\phi)&-i \sin(\phi) & 0 \\
0 & -i \sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi) & 0 \\
-i \sin(\phi) & 0 & 0 & \cos(\phi) \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

The second option doesn't make a whole lot of sense; it's not even unitary, so it's really not right. It cannot be the definition of a gate.

Comment: thank you, I forgot the minus sign in the first definition. Should I edit it and let you edit your answer accordingly ? Otherwise it might be confusing for someone reading this if they assume I did no mistake in copying the Wikipedia definition

Comment: @nathanraynal Sure. I'll edit mine now...